# SharePoint site not getting indexed

Tags: sharepoint-online

Due to a requirement I have set the option "Allow this site to appear in search results?" to No. Later I have changed that options to Yes, but none of the site content are not retrieved by search. I have re-indexed the site and a list as well and still those are not indexed.
Now 24 hours gone after making it to yes.

Appreciate if anyone can suggest a solution.

Comment: Are the lists in the lists settings also set "Allow items from this list to appear in search results"?

Comment: Yes, "Allow items from this list to appear in search results?" is set to yes.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Online, crawling happens automatically based on the defined crawl schedule. And the crawling time will increase if it is a heavy environment.

We cannot manually start a full crawl for contents or control crawl in SharePoint online.

It is recommended that open a support case if content is not being reflected as expected in search within 24 hours.

You can [contact Office 365 technical support from Support > New Service request](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/contact-support-for-business-products-admin-help-32a17ca7-6fa0-4870-8a8d-e25ba4ccfd4b#ID0EAADAAA=online).

Provide as much additional information as possible to describe your issue.

[Introduction to SharePoint Online Search](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Support-Blog/Introduction-to-SharePoint-Online-Search/ba-p/170708)